# Using alternative content if url for flash file is bad

Tags: flash, default

I am trying to display a default swf file in case the supplied url for the swf file is not a valid one. 
Can somebody suggest a good way to do this?

Comment: You're incredibly vague. Is this a question about Flash or configuration of web servers? Also, describe your problem in more depth.

Comment: thanks for commenting!
This is what I am trying to do:
a) Load a flash (swf) file using javascript on my html page say banner.swf
b) If the swf file does not exist at the given path , I want to load a deafult swf file instead of displaying a blank space (say default.swf)
Can you please throw light on how this can be done?